# Java: IOException: Unterminated quoted field at end of CSV line

Tags: java, parsing, opencsv

I'm using CSVParser and CSVReader for parsing and reading csv-files.

```
 char QUOTE = '""';

 InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(content);
 CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParserBuilder()
      .withSeparator(";".charAt(0))
      .withQuoteChar(QUOTE)
      .build();
 CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(reader);
```

I faced with the following problem.
When I pass to csvParser.parseLine(currentLine)-method line with multiple semicolons at the end of csv-line (for example):

```
"GGDIRECT";"ARCIT_TEST_1";"Test table for ArcIt";500;;;
```

it returns exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Unterminated quoted field at end of CSV line
```

Comment: what are the values of parameters.getDelimiter().charAt(0) and QUOTE? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question.   new CSVParserBuilder()
      .withSeparator(";".charAt(0))

Comment: What is the value of QUOTE? also review the update you did, I think `.withSeparator(";".charAt(0))` should be `.withSeparator(";")`

Comment: Btw, `";".charAt(0)` is more easily written as `';'`.

Comment: juanlumn, withSeparator-method require char as a parameter type. This why I use: ";".charAt(0)

Comment: Another way - is to use .withSeparator(';') .  But the problem with exception continues

Comment: And is: QUOTE is a Double quotes.  ""

Comment: The code as given cannot possibly compile, and quote char would need to be a single double quote, not a double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't used `csvParser` because you don't pass it to the `CSVReader` constructor. This means you parse with the default field separator and not ";".

I'm not near PC to check but see if another constructor accepts `reader` and `csvParser`, something like :

```
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(reader, linesToSkip, csvParser);
```

**EDIT**

It looks like I have been viewing incorrect website for `CSVReader` API. However you have found the correct way to link your customised `CSVParser` with `Reader` to make `CSVReader`:

```
CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParserBuilder().withSeparator(';')
                                            .withQuoteChar('\"')
                                            .build();
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(reader).withCSVParser(csvParser).build();
```

You can verify with test:

```
String content = "\"GGDIRECT\";\"ARCIT_TEST_1\";\"Test table for ArcIt\";500;;;";
try (CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(content))) {
    csvReader.forEach(arr -> System.out.format("WRONG String[%d] = %s%n", arr.length, Arrays.toString(arr)));
}

try (CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(new StringReader(content)).withCSVParser(csvParser).build()) {
    csvReader.forEach(arr -> System.out.format("RIGHT String[%d] = %s%n", arr.length, Arrays.toString(arr)));
}
```

Prints:

```
WRONG String[1] = [GGDIRECT";"ARCIT_TEST_1";"Test table for ArcIt";500;;;]
RIGHT String[7] = [GGDIRECT, ARCIT_TEST_1, Test table for ArcIt, 500, , , ]
```

Comment: Hm, in my version of opencsv, CSVReader has no puplic constructor with multiple arguments. Only new CSVReader(reader)

Comment: I'll update when near Pc, the call you need would require access to both of reader+csvParser.

Comment: I found the way:  CSVReaderBuilder(inputStream).withCSVParser(parcer).build()

Answer (score 0):

The exception you encountered, "java.io.IOException: Unterminated quoted field at end of CSV line," occurs when the CSV line ends with an incomplete quoted field. In your case, it seems that the last field in the CSV line is empty and ends with multiple semicolons.

To resolve this issue, you have a few options:

1. Ensure that the CSV file is properly formatted: It's important to follow the CSV format rules when creating the file. Each field should be properly enclosed in quotes if needed and separated by the defined separator (in your case, a semicolon). If a field is empty, it should still have an empty value enclosed within the quotes.
2. Modify the CSV line before parsing: If you have control over the CSV file generation, you can modify the line before passing it to the `parseLine()` method. You can remove the extra semicolons at the end of the line to avoid the exception, or use this csv format for nullable values

```
    "GGDIRECT";"ARCIT_TEST_1";"Test table for ArcIt";500;"";"";
```

3. Handle the exception gracefully: If modifying the CSV file is not an option, you can catch the `IOException` and handle it gracefully in your code. For example, you can log the error and skip the problematic line or take any other appropriate action.

Note that the specific solution depends on your use case and the requirements of your application.

Comment: Was this answer generated by chatGPT?

Comment: I tried handle  "GGDIRECT";"ARCIT_TEST_1";"Test table for ArcIt";500;"";"";     But receive exception:  Unterminated quoted field at end of CSV line. Beginning of lost text [';'].  Also I tried "GGDIRECT";"ARCIT_TEST_1";"Test table for ArcIt";500;"";""   and error is Unterminated quoted field at end of CSV line. Beginning of lost text [].

Answer (score 0):

Try defining QUOTE as a single double quote character: `"`